# is safari extension global page JS able to modify a tab's DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, safari, safari-extension

This page describes the Windows and Tabs api for Safari extensions:

[The Windows and Tabs API](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW1)

My question is: Does Javascript loaded in the global page have the ability to manipulate a tab's DOM?

Or, do I have to inject JS into a page as a Start / End Script in order to get access to a tab's DOM?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to inject JS into a page as a Start / End Script in order to get access to a tab's DOM?

Yes.